# Pinout for a 2047 chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, pinout

What is the pinout for a 2047 IC?

Here is an underside of the circuit:
[image]
Unfortunately, the quality of my camera is not good enough to capture the writing on the chip (the writing is completely invisible on the image because it is very faint) but it says 2047 cHC at the bottom.

The circuit is part of a remote control device for a car (made by "The Gift Scholars Ltd") and so is very simple. Here is an image of the top of the circuit.
[image]
I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Hi, Before anyone can tell you the pinout, they have to identify what the IC is and likely read its datasheet. So please [Edit] your question and add more context & details, including: (a) What makes you believe the IC is called a 2047? Does it have 2047 marked on it? If so, did you know that the top marking of an IC does *not* mean that this is its actual part number? (b) Please add photos of the IC & whole device into the question. (c) Why do you believe the IC is made by "The Gift Scholars"? Or did you mean that the overall device is made by them? (d) What is the overall device? Thanks.

Comment: (Related to point (a) above: For example, "2047" could be a manufacturing date code meaning year 20**20**, week **47** - hence why more details and context are needed, to avoid readers wasting time trying to identify an IC, when the number turns out to be a date code.)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, I will edit my answer now.

Comment: Please add an image of the IC and possibly the device it's in.

Comment: why are you asking about the chip?

Comment: @MichaelWilliams - Thanks for adding photos & info. However, now you have explained the IC is from an RC car transmitter, then based on your [previous question](/questions/582499) and as explained in its answer, you don't need to understand the full pinout of the "2047" IC to be able to control the transmitter from a PC. So to extend the comment above: *Why* are you asking about the ICs pinout? What would you do with that information, if you could get it? *That* is the question you should be asking IMHO (cf XY-problem). I suspect the needed info can be reverse-engineered from the photo. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the problem at hand but I was thinking that the only way for me to wire up the buttons to the relay board (reference previous question but not relevant) was via the chip since they are the only exposed wires which are also the center for all circuit operations. In short, my thought process was that I would connect the output from the chip that comes from a button to another circuit.  Hence, I wanted the pinout so I could know which pins to connect to. Thanks for holding up with my inexperience @SamGibson and everyone for all of the help thus far.